# Laravel auto redirect to public url

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

my laravel is redirecting to the "public" url automatically.
my laravel it's in installed in a subdomain, with DOCUMENTROOT in the public folder, but whenever I go in any route other than `"/"` it adds `"public/"` in the middle

i'm using laravel 5.8

Comment: What we server are you using?

Comment: im using king.host, is a shared hosting

Comment: What is the path to your laravel installation?

Comment: Ensure you have `/public/.htaccess` installed https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/installation#web-server-configuration and mod_rewrite is installed

Comment: is the original of the installation